# How do you access a form's controls using MVP

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, mvp

Hopefully this image is readable on here...

[image]

This is my first project implementing MVP. I've got three classes. My main form, aptly named `FrmMain`, `FrmMainPresenter`, and then `MainOps` which has some extra stuff.

On `FrmMain`, I've got a reference to `FrmMainPresenter`, and on `FrmMainPresenter` I have a reference to `FrmMain`.

An event on `FrmMain` calls a method on `FrmMainPresenter`.

`FrmMainPresenter` is *supposed* to get a control from the `FrmMain` reference and call a method on `MainOps` that accepts a `GridControl` and `Collection<Control>`.

However, upon trying to access the appropriate Grid and Collection within `FrmMainPresenter`, it tells me `FrmMain` doesn't contain a definition for those controls

Code on `FrmMain`:

```
    private void genericCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _presenter.CheckBoxCheckedChanged();
    }
```

Code on `FrmMainPresenter`:

```
    public void CheckBoxCheckedChanged()
    {
        if (!_view.SuppressCheckedChanged)
            _mo.UpdateFilter(_view.gdcSVNDefaultView, _view.Controls);
    }
```

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. I didn't think this was correct, but my only guess was to go and set the necessary controls to public in the Designer file, but that didn't work. Same results.

I guess the issue is because the interface for my form doesn't have the gridview / controls collection defined, my presenter class can't see it. But even then I'm not sure how I'd properly define it in the interface so that I could implement it on the form.

Comment: Is your problem that your code is not compiling, or does it throw an exception during runtime (and if so, what does the exception and its stacktrace tell).

Comment: If you use an interface, declare a method which returns the desired controls. In your class implementing the interface, you also implement this method then. (Alternatively, instead of using method you could declare a property with a getter in the interface.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either make the `Control` in `FrmMain` public through the designer properties or add a public getter to the `FrmMain` code which the `FrmMainPresenter` can then access.

There are probably another half dozen ways this can be ultimately achieved but these are probably the 2 most common and easiest ways to do achieve your goal.

Comment: Hm, well that certainly worked. Added the Getters definitions to my interface then implemented the actual methods in the class. I'll wait a little bit for other answers, then probably mark this correct.

Comment: @Sab699, i think that is the answer :) I said in the comments something to the same effect (without having noticed this answer yet).